# How do i change the position of the textfield inside UISearchBar

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield, uisearchbar, ios11

My UISearchBar textfield sticks too close to the glassIcon. I need them to be separated by atleast 10 points.

[image: UISearchBar problem]

P.S - this is on iOS 11.2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check this out [UISearchBar Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uisearchbar) by Apple and take a look at **searchTextPositionAdjustment**.

To create a gap of 10 pixels between the icon and the text you could do:

```
 searchBar.searchTextPositionAdjustment = UIOffset(horizontal: 10, vertical: 0)
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks. Works like a charm! :D